# TCLAP: output list of all parameters along with their respective values

Tags: c++, command-line-interface

I would like to output a list of all specified parameters along with their respective values (either those passed, or the default value if not passed through the command line).

Getting the parameter names is not a big deal when iterating the `Arg` list obtained from `CmdLine::getArgList()`. However, the values cannot be accessed from here since they are stored in the subclasses inheriting from `Arg`, e.g. `ValueArg<T>` or `SwitchArg`. The information about the values is thus not accessible from the base class.

Is there still a way to get this done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I don't think there is an easy way to do this.  TCLAP was really designed to allow the various Args to be handled individually and this particular use case hasn't come up before.

I'm wondering if there's some sort of unsafe cast you can do that simply calls getValue?

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to avoid beforehand. Anyway, I will now go with a sequence of `dynamic_cast`s turing the `Arg*` into whichever inherited classes I'm using, such as `TCLAP::ValueArg<uint32_t>*`, `TCLAP::ValueArg<std::string>*` and so on.